# Pandas: Accumulated Shares Holdings per Ticker per Day from a List of Trades

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have a pd.DataFrame (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame) with some stock trades.

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-01-15', '2021-01-21', '2021-02-28', '2021-01-30', '2021-02-16', '2021-03-22', '2021-01-08', '2021-03-02', '2021-02-25', '2021-04-04', '2021-03-15', '2021-04-08'], 'Ticker': ['MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL','MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL','MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL'], 'Quantity': [2,3,7,2,6,4,-3,8,-2,9,11,1]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

          Date Ticker  Quantity
0   2021-01-15   MFST         2
1   2021-01-21   AMZN         3
2   2021-02-28   GOOG         7
3   2021-01-30   AAPL         2
4   2021-02-16   MFST         6
5   2021-03-22   AMZN         4
6   2021-01-08   GOOG        -3
7   2021-03-02   AAPL         8
8   2021-02-25   MFST        -2
9   2021-04-04   AMZN         9
10  2021-03-15   GOOG        11
11  2021-04-08   AAPL         1
```

Quantity refers to the number of shares bought.

I am looking for an efficient way to create a new df which contains the number of shares for each Ticker per day.

The first trade was on 2021-01-08 and the last on 2021-04-08. I want a new dataframe that contains **all days** between those to dates as rows and the tickers as columns. **Values shall be the number of shares I hold at a specific day**. Hence, if I buy 4 shares of a stock at 2021-03-15 (assuming no further buying or selling) I will have them from 2021-03-15 till 2021-04-08 which should be represented as a 4 in every row for this specific ticker. If I decide to buy more shares this number will change on that day and all following days.

Could be something like this:

```
         Date   MFST  AMZN    GOOG    APPL
  2021-01-08      2     3       1       0
  2021-01-09      2     3       1       0
  2021-01-10      2     3       1       0

       ...

  2021-04-08      2     3       1       7
```

My first guess was to create an empty DataFrame and then iterate with two for loops over all its Dates and Tickers. However, I think that is not the most efficient way. I am thankful for any recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to transform your data into a tabular form, as shown on the expected output layout, as follows:

```
df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Quantity').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

If you need to aggregate `Quantity` for same date for each stock, you can use [`df.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with parameter `aggfunc='sum'`, as follows:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Quantity', aggfunc='sum').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Result:

```
         Date  AAPL  AMZN  GOOG  MFST
0  2021-01-21     0     3     0     0
1  2021-02-28     0     0     1     0
2  2021-03-15     0     0     0     2
3  2021-04-30     7     0     0     0
```

**Additional Test Case:**

To showcase the aggregation function of `df.pivot_table()`, I have added some data as follows:

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-03-15',
  '2021-01-21',
  '2021-01-21',
  '2021-02-28',
  '2021-02-28',
  '2021-04-30',
  '2021-04-30'],
 'Ticker': ['MFST', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'GOOG', 'AAPL', 'AAPL'],
 'Quantity': [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 2]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(data)


         Date Ticker  Quantity
0  2021-03-15   MFST         2
1  2021-01-21   AMZN         3
2  2021-01-21   AMZN         4
3  2021-02-28   GOOG         1
4  2021-02-28   GOOG         2
5  2021-04-30   AAPL         7
6  2021-04-30   AAPL         2


df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Quantity', aggfunc='sum').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index().fillna(0, downcast='infer')


         Date  AAPL  AMZN  GOOG  MFST
0  2021-01-21     0     7     0     0
1  2021-02-28     0     0     3     0
2  2021-03-15     0     0     0     2
3  2021-04-30     9     0     0     0
```

### Edit

Based on latest requirement:

> The first trade was on 2021-03-15 and the last on 2021-04-30. I want a
> new dataframe that contains all days between those to dates as rows
> and the tickers as columns. Values shall be the number of shares I
> hold at a specific day. Hence, if I buy 4 shares of a stock at
> 2021-03-15 (assuming no further buying or selling) I will have them
> from 2021-03-15 till 2021-04-30 which should be represented as a 4 in
> every row for this specific ticker. If I decide to buy more shares
> this number will change on that day and all following days.

Here is the enhanced solution:

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-01-15', '2021-01-21', '2021-02-28', '2021-01-30', '2021-02-16', '2021-03-22', '2021-01-08', '2021-03-02', '2021-02-25', '2021-04-04', '2021-03-15', '2021-04-08'], 'Ticker': ['MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL','MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL','MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL'], 'Quantity': [2,3,7,2,6,4,-3,8,-2,9,11,1]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values('Date')

df1 = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D')
df1['Ticker'] = df1['Ticker'].ffill().bfill()
df1['Quantity'] = df1['Quantity'].fillna(0)

df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Ticker', values='Quantity', aggfunc='sum').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df3 = df2[['Date']].join(df2.iloc[:,1:].cumsum())
```

**Result:**

```
print(df3)


         Date  AAPL  AMZN  GOOG  MFST
0  2021-01-08     0     0    -3     0
1  2021-01-09     0     0    -3     0
2  2021-01-10     0     0    -3     0
3  2021-01-11     0     0    -3     0
4  2021-01-12     0     0    -3     0
5  2021-01-13     0     0    -3     0
6  2021-01-14     0     0    -3     0
7  2021-01-15     0     0    -3     2
8  2021-01-16     0     0    -3     2
9  2021-01-17     0     0    -3     2
10 2021-01-18     0     0    -3     2
11 2021-01-19     0     0    -3     2
12 2021-01-20     0     0    -3     2
13 2021-01-21     0     3    -3     2
14 2021-01-22     0     3    -3     2
15 2021-01-23     0     3    -3     2
16 2021-01-24     0     3    -3     2
17 2021-01-25     0     3    -3     2
18 2021-01-26     0     3    -3     2
19 2021-01-27     0     3    -3     2
20 2021-01-28     0     3    -3     2
21 2021-01-29     0     3    -3     2
22 2021-01-30     2     3    -3     2
23 2021-01-31     2     3    -3     2
24 2021-02-01     2     3    -3     2
25 2021-02-02     2     3    -3     2
26 2021-02-03     2     3    -3     2
27 2021-02-04     2     3    -3     2
28 2021-02-05     2     3    -3     2
29 2021-02-06     2     3    -3     2
30 2021-02-07     2     3    -3     2
31 2021-02-08     2     3    -3     2
32 2021-02-09     2     3    -3     2
33 2021-02-10     2     3    -3     2
34 2021-02-11     2     3    -3     2
35 2021-02-12     2     3    -3     2
36 2021-02-13     2     3    -3     2
37 2021-02-14     2     3    -3     2
38 2021-02-15     2     3    -3     2
39 2021-02-16     2     3    -3     8
40 2021-02-17     2     3    -3     8
41 2021-02-18     2     3    -3     8
42 2021-02-19     2     3    -3     8
43 2021-02-20     2     3    -3     8
44 2021-02-21     2     3    -3     8
45 2021-02-22     2     3    -3     8
46 2021-02-23     2     3    -3     8
47 2021-02-24     2     3    -3     8
48 2021-02-25     2     3    -3     6
49 2021-02-26     2     3    -3     6
50 2021-02-27     2     3    -3     6
51 2021-02-28     2     3     4     6
52 2021-03-01     2     3     4     6
53 2021-03-02    10     3     4     6
54 2021-03-03    10     3     4     6
55 2021-03-04    10     3     4     6
56 2021-03-05    10     3     4     6
57 2021-03-06    10     3     4     6
58 2021-03-07    10     3     4     6
59 2021-03-08    10     3     4     6
60 2021-03-09    10     3     4     6
61 2021-03-10    10     3     4     6
62 2021-03-11    10     3     4     6
63 2021-03-12    10     3     4     6
64 2021-03-13    10     3     4     6
65 2021-03-14    10     3     4     6
66 2021-03-15    10     3    15     6
67 2021-03-16    10     3    15     6
68 2021-03-17    10     3    15     6
69 2021-03-18    10     3    15     6
70 2021-03-19    10     3    15     6
71 2021-03-20    10     3    15     6
72 2021-03-21    10     3    15     6
73 2021-03-22    10     7    15     6
74 2021-03-23    10     7    15     6
75 2021-03-24    10     7    15     6
76 2021-03-25    10     7    15     6
77 2021-03-26    10     7    15     6
78 2021-03-27    10     7    15     6
79 2021-03-28    10     7    15     6
80 2021-03-29    10     7    15     6
81 2021-03-30    10     7    15     6
82 2021-03-31    10     7    15     6
83 2021-04-01    10     7    15     6
84 2021-04-02    10     7    15     6
85 2021-04-03    10     7    15     6
86 2021-04-04    10    16    15     6
87 2021-04-05    10    16    15     6
88 2021-04-06    10    16    15     6
89 2021-04-07    10    16    15     6
90 2021-04-08    11    16    15     6
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint.
How would you go from there to a DataFrame which contains the number of shares per Ticker and per day?

Comment: @Philipp  Sorry, can you explain a little bit more about your question ?   What exactly you want to know ?

Comment: @Philipp  Would there be more than one entry for each ticker for each date ?  If no, just use my first part of solution to get the layout you want.  If yes, use the second.  Both are in tabular form with tickers as columns as per your desired layout.

Comment: Sure. The first trade was on 2021-03-15 and the last on 2021-04-30. I want a new dataframe that contains all days between those to dates as rows and the tickers as columns. Values shall be the number of shares I hold at a specific day. Hence, if I buy 4 shares of a stock at 2021-03-15 (assuming no further buying or selling) I will have them from 2021-03-15 till  2021-04-30 which should be represented as a 4 in every row for this specific ticker. If I decide to buy more shares this number will change on that day and all following days.

Comment: @Philipp  Your sample data currently has date in January and February, would you please also craft a set of sample data including all your test cases ?   In the meantime, I will try to enhance the solution.  When you have your data ready, I'll test on your data to prove the result.  Do you think this fair ?

Comment: Actually, I just started with those few trades. I created a few more, but there is no larger set.
Nevertheless, this can be a test-set can be useful.

`data = {'Date': ['2021-01-15', '2021-01-21', '2021-02-28', '2021-01-30', '2021-02-16', '2021-03-22', '2021-01-08', '2021-03-02', '2021-02-25', '2021-04-04', '2021-03-15', '2021-04-08'],
'Ticker': ['MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL','MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL','MFST', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'AAPL'],
'Quantity': [2,3,7,2,6,4,-3,8,-2,9,11,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: @Philipp  Find my edit above rewritten with enhancement of your revised requirement.

Comment: @Philipp  Great to see you solved the problem.  As you now have enough reputation (> 15) to upvote, please also upvote the answer (this is a norm to also upvote an answer when you accept an answer).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.groupby`

```
df.groupby(['Date']).agg('sum')
```